# Sum of files (including hidden) takes 92 gb, but Windows 10 says 303 gb are used

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

I know this questions has been asked a thousand times already and in a thousand different websites.
But I haven never seen such great discrepancy (in % and in absolute values).
200 gb is a lot. And is 200% more than what's actually being used.

Btw, I'm using  `Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 17134) (17134.rs4_release.180410-1804)`

Edit: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/216243/hard-drive-shows-122-gb-used-after-fresh-install-of-windows-18-gb-of-actual-fil?rq=1) is not the case here, because the issue here is occuring the the disk T and the OS was installed in the disk "C".

**Disk Propreties says 303 GB are used.**

[image: Disk Propreties says 303 GB are used.]

**But I really don't understand how. The sum of all files (including hidden ones) is just 92 GB.**
[image: But I really don't understand how. The sum of all files (including hidden ones) is just 92 GB.]

**And as you can see, Disk Cleanup can't really help me here.**
[image: As you can see, Disk Cleanup can't really help me here.]

**Hidden files and system protected files are shown to me and I'm the OS has only one user**
[image: Hidden files and system protected files are shown to me and I'm the OS has only one user]

**Final edit -- Solution**: after following Appleoddity's suggestion and installing WinDirStat, I found out that my Recycle Bin is corrupted.
[image: corrupted recycle bin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re misinterpreting your results.

Disk properties shows 303 GB is used. This is the accurate information.

You are then attempting to check the properties of the T:\ folder and expecting it to match. You say, “the sum of all files (including hidden ones)...” But file explorer does not calculate the size of hidden folders. Those two check boxes, `Read-Only` and `Hidden` only indicate the current folder contains files or folders that are hidden and read-only. And you can change that by changing the check box. Although I wouldn’t recommend doing that on a root folder.

In addition, file explorer can’t access folders that your user account can’t access. Such as other user folders or System Volume Information. So it doesn’t calculate the size of inaccessible folders.

The disk properties number is correct. If you want to confirm this and find where the data is used, then you can use my favorite tool - [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net). Make sure you “Run as Admin” or it too can’t access protected folders.

EDIT: I tested this on Windows 10, and found that even when a folder had the HIDDEN or SYSTEM attribute, or both, it still counted in the total storage. I've found reports that other versions of Windows do not do this. Maybe it is no longer an issue in Windows 10. Therefore, the problem is most likely "inaccessible" folders that can't be calculated.

Comment: I added another screenshot to show that I actually I'm including hidden files and protected files.

Comment: Again, it's not only hidden / system files. It is also folders you can't access. You can't access System Volume Information. The extra space could literally be nothing more than restore points.

Comment: It was a corrupt recycle bin.

Comment: Wow. Ok. Did you fix that with chkdsk? The thought crossed my mind, but I thought it was unlikely the issue here. Glad you sorted it. If you haven't ran `chkdsk T: /f` you probably should.

Comment: The thought didn't even cross my mind. After using WinDirStrat I was in awe... How the heck my recyclen bin is consuming 200 gb but the Disk Cleanup says it's using < 1 MB?

Thank for the help man :) Have a good week!